# call web api by passing simple and complex parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-web-api-routing

Getting an error message of no http resource or action found in controller. In a web api I have a from body and from uri parameter.

```
[HttpPost]        
public IHttpActionResult processfields(
    [FromUri]string field1,
    [FromUri]string field2, 
    [FromBody] string field3, 
    [FromUri]string field4
){...}
```

In the client I want to call the web api by doing--

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    //set up client
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


     var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     values.Add("field1", field1);
     values.Add("field2", field2);
     values.Add("field3", field3);
     values.Add("field4", filed4);


     var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
     try
     {

         HttpResponseMessage Res = client.PostAsync("api/home/processfields", new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
         var result = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     }
}
```

While debugging, it executes the last line above but nothing happens and error message says--

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:1234/api/home/processfields'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'home' that matches the request."}

my webapi.config has

```
// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: You are sending everything in the body of the request while the action has been configured to expect parameters from the URI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`field1`, `field2` and `field4` parameters are expected in the Url, not in the request body. That's why the request Url should look like: `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:1234/api/home/processfields?field1=value1&field2=value2&field4=value4`

`field3` is deserialized from the body. However as it is string parameter, request body should be built not as JSON object:

```
{
  "field3": "value3"
}
```

but as JSON string:

```
"value3"
```

Here is adjusted client code that should work:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    //set up client
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var requestUri = new Uri($"api/home/processfields?field1={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(field1)}&field2={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(field2)}&field4={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(field4)}", UriKind.Relative);
    var content = new StringContent($"\"{field3}\"", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, looking at the Web API method signature, I don't think there's any JSON involved here at all. So I think you can skip setting the `Accept` header. (If the `[FromBody]` parameter were a complex object rather than a string, then JSON serialization would likely come into play.)

Second, never use `.Result` with HttpClient. It is an async-only API and you should be using `async` / `await`, otherwise you're just inviting deadlocks.

Finally, as others have pointed out, field1, field2, and field4 go in the query string, not the body. If you want a more structured way to do this, and with less ceremony overall, consider using [Flurl](https://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) (disclaimer: I'm the author), which uses HttpClient under the hood:

```
using Flurl.Http;

var result = await BaseUrl
    .AppendPathSegment("api/home/processfields")
    .SetQueryParams(new { field1, field2, field4 })
    .PostStringAsync(field3)
    .ReceiveString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bodyClass obj = new bodyClass();
obj.empName= "your param value";
string DATA = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

var client = new HttpClient();
HttpContent content = new StringContent(DATA, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage messge = client.PostAsync("your api url", content).Result;

if (messge.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
      string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```