# How to send C# POST Request with JSON Array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, post

I am working on a C# console client, I should call a REST API call with the POST method. In the POST call I should send a JSON with an array in it. In all the examples I find only Dictionary<string, string> which are converted via FormURLEncodedContent to the desired data type. But how can I do that with an array?

```
private Boolean book(String[] ticketIds)
{

    var order = new Order
    {
        ticketIds = ticketIds,
        creditcardCVC = "",
        creditcardNumber = "",
        creditcardType = "",
    };

    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   


    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    

    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.PostAsync("book", content).Result; // Blocking call! Program will wait here until a response is received or a timeout occurs.


    if (responseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
```

[call web api by passing simple and complex parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48484978/call-web-api-by-passing-simple-and-complex-parameter)
In this amount is in approximately what I want however again without array.

FROM THE OTHER QUESTION(That you don´t have to look after it):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    //set up client
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


     var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     values.Add("field1", field1);
     values.Add("field2", field2);
     values.Add("field3", field3);
     values.Add("field4", filed4);


     var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
     try
     {

         HttpResponseMessage Res = client.PostAsync("api/home/processfields", new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
         var result = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     }
}
```

The JSON I want to send should look like this.

```
{
    "ticketIds": [
        "7"
    ],
    "creditcardType": "MASTERCARD",
    "creditcardNumber": "1234567890",
    "creditcardCVC": "123"
}
```

Order Class

```
public class Order
    {
        public String[] ticketIds { get; set; }
        public String creditcardType { get; set; }
        public String creditcardNumber { get; set; }
        public String creditcardCVC { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: you have to decide what are you going to use json content or I can see FormUrlEncodedContent ? And where is your Order class? And why you are creating an empty order?

Comment: I have adapted the question and inserted the Order class. The empty order does not matter, it is checked server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Solution for the Problem

```
private Boolean book(String[] ticketIds)
        {

            var order = new Order
            {
                ticketIds = ticketIds,
                creditcardCVC = "",
                creditcardNumber = "",
                creditcardType = "",
            };


            var opt = new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true };
            string strJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<Order>(order, opt);

            //Console.WriteLine(strJson);

            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.PostAsync("book", new StringContent(strJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result; // Blocking call! Program will wait here until a response is received or a timeout occurs.


            if (responseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
```